# SOAP API Integration Assistance

Tags: javascript, soap

Good day StackOverflow, I am currently integrating a credit check SOAP API, I was given some sample code without a *package.json* file, so I have no idea as to the development environment. Here is the sample code I was given:

```js
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var bsplit = require('buffer-split');

//process.env.http_proxy = 'http://host:port';

var xmlData = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://webServices/">' +
    '<soapenv:Header/>' +
    '<soapenv:Body>' +
    '   <web:DoNormalEnquiryStream>' +
    '       <request>' +
    '           <pUsrnme>*****</pUsrnme>' +
    '           <pPasswrd>*****</pPasswrd>' +
    '           <pVersion>1.0</pVersion>' +
    '           <pOrigin>QA-SOAPUI</pOrigin>' +
    '           <pOrigin_Version>1.0</pOrigin_Version>' +
    '           <pInput_Format>XML</pInput_Format>' +
    '           <pTransaction>' +
    '               <![CDATA[<Transactions>' +
    '                   <Search_Criteria>' +
    '                       <CS_Data>Y</CS_Data>' +
    '                       <CPA_Plus_NLR_Data>Y</CPA_Plus_NLR_Data>' +
    '                       <Deeds_Data>N</Deeds_Data>' +
    '                       <Directors_Data>N</Directors_Data>' +
    '                       <Identity_number></Identity_number>' +
    '                       <Surname></Surname>' +
    '                       <Forename></Forename>' +
    '                       <Forename2/>' +
    '                       <Forename3/>' +
    '                       <Gender>M</Gender>' +
    '                       <Passport_flag>N</Passport_flag>' +
    '                       <DateOfBirth>19820914</DateOfBirth>' +
    '                       <Address1></Address1>' +
    '                       <Address2></Address2>' +
    '                       <Address3/><Address4/>' +
    '                       <PostalCode></PostalCode>' +
    '                       <HomeTelCode/>' +
    '                       <HomeTelNo/>' +
    '                       <WorkTelCode/>' +
    '                       <WorkTelNo/>' +
    '                       <CellTelNo/>' +
    '                       <ResultType>JPDF2</ResultType>' +
    '                       <RunCodix>N</RunCodix>' +
    '                       <Adrs_Mandatory>N</Adrs_Mandatory>' +
    '                       <Enq_Purpose>12</Enq_Purpose>' +
    '                       <Run_CompuScore>N</Run_CompuScore>' +
    '                       <ClientConsent>Y</ClientConsent>' +
    '                       </Search_Criteria>' +
    '            </Transactions>]]>' +
    '          </pTransaction>' +
    '       </request>' +
    '   </web:DoNormalEnquiryStream>' +
    '   </soapenv:Body>' +
    '   </soapenv:Envelope>';

request({
    url: "api.myapiurl.com/soap-api",
    encoding:null,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "content-type": "text/xml"
    },
    body: xmlData
}, function (error, response, body){

    var delim = new Buffer('--uuid');
    var result = bsplit(body,delim);

    var attBuffs = [];
    var attBuffsStartIndex = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        if(result[i].toString().indexOf("Content-Type: application/octet-stream") > 0){
            attBuffs.push(result[i]);
            var trimmedString = result[i].toString();
            attBuffsStartIndex.push(trimmedString.indexOf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary")+37);
        }
    }

    fs.open('JsonFile.json', 'w', function (err, fd) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
        }

        fs.write(fd, attBuffs[0], attBuffsStartIndex[0], attBuffs[0].length - attBuffsStartIndex[0], null, function (err) {
            if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
            fs.close(fd, function () {
                console.log('JSON File written to file');
            })
        });
    });

    fs.open('PdfFile.pdf', 'w', function (err, fd) {
        if (err) {
            throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
        }

        fs.write(fd, attBuffs[1], attBuffsStartIndex[1], attBuffs[1].length - attBuffsStartIndex[1], null, function (err) {
            if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
            fs.close(fd, function () {
                console.log('PDF File written to file');
            })
        });
    });
});
```

I am having some difficulty getting this code to run. I thought it might need the [RequireJS API], but after doing some research I strongly believe it's actually the [Request HTTP Client](https://github.com/request/request). I really struggling to get this sample code running. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Addition**
I am aware that this is it requires nodejs. But I have not been able to figure out how to progress from there.

---

**Addition**

If anyone is interested native node modules such as *net, fs etc* are not meant to be run from a browser, so this code will not work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Create a project directory**

`mkdir ~/projects/credit`

(If `~/projects` doesn't exist, create it with `mkdir ~/projects` first or create the new directory wherever you want.)

**2. Change to the new directory**

`cd ~/projects/credit`

**2. Create a file for your sample code**

`touch sample.js`

**3. Paste in your sample code in the sample.js file**

**4. Install the request and buffer-split packages**

`npm install request buffer-split`

This should generate a `package.json` file in your new project directory, along with the `node_modules` directory with the installed modules.

**5. Run the file**

Assuming you have Node installed...

`node sample.js`

Comment: Thank you @Troy Carlson, your answer really pointed me in the right direction. I used npm and webpack to start a project, run it on a test server and I seem to be getting further. Thank you!